# CodeIgniter active record count mysql records according value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

What would be wrong with my active record query the SUM function works fine but the count parts returns the count of all records.

```
$this->db->select(
                        '
                         t1.account_balance, 
                         t2.CustomerName AS customer,
                         t2.CustomerId,
                         SUM(IF(t3.Bargain="Sale",t3.TotalAmount,0)) AS total_sale,
                         SUM(IF(t3.Bargain="Purchase",t3.TotalAmount,0)) AS total_buy,
                         COUNT(IF(t3.Bargain="Sale",t3.Bargain,0)) AS count_sale,
                         COUNT(IF(t3.Bargain="Purchase",t3.Bargain,0)) AS count_buy,
                         '
                     ,FALSE);
    $this->db->from("balances AS t1");
    $this->db->join("customer AS t2","t2.CustomerId = t1.customer_id","left");
    $this->db->join("gold_order AS t3","t3.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId","left");
    $this->db->group_by("t3.CustomerId");
    $object = $this->db->get();
```

Result:

[image]

What I want the count_sale should be 3 and count_buy should be 4:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$this->db->select(
                    '
                     t1.account_balance, 
                     t2.CustomerName AS customer,
                     t2.CustomerId,
                     SUM(IF(t3.Bargain="Sale",t3.TotalAmount,0)) AS total_sale,
                     SUM(IF(t3.Bargain="Purchase",t3.TotalAmount,0)) AS total_buy,
                     SUM(IF(t3.Bargain="Sale",1,0)) AS count_sale,
                     SUM(IF(t3.Bargain="Purchase",1,0)) AS count_buy,
                     '
                 ,FALSE);
$this->db->from("balances AS t1");
$this->db->join("customer AS t2","t2.CustomerId = t1.customer_id","left");
$this->db->join("gold_order AS t3","t3.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId","left");
$this->db->group_by("t3.CustomerId");
$object = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: You are well come. If its OK then please accept as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('
                         t1.account_balance, 
                         t2.CustomerName AS customer,
                         t2.CustomerId,
                         SUM(IF(t3.Bargain="Sale",t3.TotalAmount,0)) AS total_sale,
                         SUM(IF(t3.Bargain="Purchase",t3.TotalAmount,0)) AS total_buy,
                        (SELECT count(*) from gold_order where gold_order.Bargain="Sale") AS count_sale,
                         (SELECT count(*) from gold_order where gold_order.Bargain="Purchase") AS count_buy,
                         '
                     ,FALSE);
    $this->db->from("balances AS t1");
    $this->db->join("customer AS t2","t2.CustomerId = t1.customer_id","left");
    $this->db->join("gold_order AS t3","t3.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId","left");
    $this->db->group_by("t3.CustomerId");
    $object = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Got error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * from gold_order where gold_order.Bargain = "Sale") AS count_sale, COUNT' at line 1

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari let me rewrite it

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari i have edited my answer. try it now